# Capturing date time from the view into the database MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I created MVC application that has a text box posted to the database. When the text box is posted, I want to capture today's date  from the view and store it into the table. How do I capture the date and time the view that posted and how do I pass this information into row Date within the database? Appreciate any help.

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Pay(int accountNumber)
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Pay(Payments payment )
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DB.Payment.Add(payment);
            DB.SaveChanges();
            var service = new Accounts(DB);
            service.Updatepayee(payment.AccountNumber);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Payments Class

```
public class Payments

   public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int AccountNumber {get; set;}


        [RegularExpression(@"(^$)|(^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})|(^((\d{1})|(\d{2}))/((\d{1})|(\d{2}))/(\d{4})\s((\d{1})|(\d{2}))[:]{1}((\d{1})|(\d{2}))[:]{1}((\d{1})|(\d{2}))\s((AM)|(PM)))", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        //Navigation property to check the account 

 public virtual AccountNumber accountNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Pay View

```
 @model Credits.View.Payments

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Pay"; }

 <h2>Payments</h2>


 @using (Html.BeginForm())  {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

     <div class="form-horizontal">
         <h4>Transaction</h4>
         <hr />
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
         <div class="form-group">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
             <div class="col-md-10">
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
           </div>
         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
             <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                 <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
             </div>
         </div>
     </div> }



 <div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Home") </div>

 @section Scripts {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") }
```

Comment: Your `TransactionDate` has a regular-expression validator that is tied to a specific culture and formatting. Is this intentional? Are you prepared to reject an otherwise valid 24-hour date/time format as invalid?

Comment: It worked after removing the regular-expression and thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you set it in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pay(Payments payment )
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        payment.TransactionDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        DB.Payment.Add(payment);
        DB.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Date has added but the transaction didn't work?? The number I posted in the text box didn't send the data to the table?

Comment: @Dai may be on the track. A date value carries no format. Your regex could perhaps be applied to a textbox but not the property itself.

Comment: How do i alter please?

Comment: For a start, try removing the regex attribute.

Comment: Gustav thank you very much it worked after removing the regex :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Pay(Payments payment )
{
    var d=DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        Payments p=new() Payments{
       AccountNumber=p.AccountNumber,
      Amount=payment.Amount,
     TransactionDate=d
};

        DB.Payment.Add(p);
        DB.SaveChanges();
```